# Chef API: Adding runlists to a node

Tags: rest, configuration, chef-infra

I am trying to figure out how to use the [Chef API](https://docs.getchef.com/api_chef_server.html#roles) to add a runlist to a node, such that, when I go to the `https://mychefserver/nodes/myapp01` node, I see the runlist under the **Run List** section.

But the Chef API doesn't appear to allow this. Am I wrong, if so, what's the endpoint and how do I call it?

Comment: I think a [PUT /organizations/name/nodes/name](https://docs.getchef.com/api_chef_server.html#id52) allows you to do this after retrieving it via `GET` and modifying the `run_list` part prior to uploading. I'm not aware of any direct way.

Comment: It's just a key in the JSON

Comment: Thanks @sethvargo (+1) - but the json key is invalid without a server context, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run lists aren't their own object, it is just part of the data in the Node object so you would use the normal `GET /nodes/foo` and `PUT /nodes/foo`. The run list is under the key `run_list` and should be an array of strings.